# ID3 does not learn from train set

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have programmed this ID3 algorithm and for some reason the predicted value seems to always return None. I cannot figure out why the code does not enter the if statement in the predict function but have narrowed down the problem to that area.

I have tried changing the predict function multiple times and debugging but cannot find out why the issue persists and the feature value is not in tree[root_node]. Can someone please help with this?

```
def predict(tree, instance):
if not isinstance(tree, dict):
    return tree
else:
    root_node = next(iter(tree))
    feat_val = instance[root_node]
    if feat_val in tree[root_node]:
        return predict(tree[root_node][feat_val], instance)
    else:
        return None

def evaluate(tree, test_data_m, label):
correct_preditct = 0
wrong_preditct = 0
for index, row in test_data_m.iterrows():#for each row in the dataset
    result = predict(tree, test_data_m.loc[index])
    if result == test_data_m[label][index]:
        correct_predict += 1 #increase correct count
    else:
        wrong_predict += 1 #increase incorrect count
accuracy = correct_predict / (correct_predict + wrong_predict)
return accuracy
```